# How can I check if my laptop's 3.5mm audio port works with a microphone?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, audio, microphone

I am ordering a Logitech headset that has separate audio and mic connectors. My laptop only has one 3.5mm audio port.

How can I tell if my laptop audio port works with a microphone? I am in the process of purchasing an audio adapter to convert 2 inputs to 1 input for the laptop, but I need to check if the one on my laptop works with a mic.

Comment: What is your laptop model? Check the specs of the laptop - I'm sure it works like that these days ---- Better off - test it with the handsfree mic set you get with your phone - before ordering logitech and converter

Comment: Also depends on the pinout - there's two competing pinouts for TRSS jacks. http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/189523-final-soultion-why-most-headsets-won-t-work.html .

Comment: @Prasanna Acer Aspire V5-572G-6679

Comment: @cyberwebpoweruser according to spec at http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834314178 --> Audio Ports
    1 x Headphone/speaker/line-out jack so no mic

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In that case Scott Rhee's answer would be more helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, there's two competing, different pinouts. [Apple compatible TRRS != the standard TRRS](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/189523-final-soultion-why-most-headsets-won-t-work.html). The Android 'standard' is the more common one from what I can tell.

Secondly, look at the pictogram

[image]
indicates a combo jack

[image]
There's different pictograms for a audio out only port/mic port combo.

Finally if you've got good eyesight, a combo port should have 4 internal connectors, and a audio only one should have 3.

Comment: I just realized my laptop has no icons next to the audio port. What do I do?

Comment: Check the manual? You should generally be able to find these online.

Comment: Computer's 4 years old at this point; have thrown out the manual long ago and tore off the promotional stickers on the laptop. Stupid move, but now I'm not sure where to proceed

Comment: @cyberwebpoweruser according to spec at http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834314178 --> Audio Ports
    1 x Headphone/speaker/line-out jack so no mic

Answer (score 2):

If you've bought the headset already and are going to buy an adaptor, an USB sound adaptor can help you avoid thinking about pinout differences. This is an example. I actually haven't used this particular product but there are so many products like this for very cheap price.

[This product itself is a sound card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A3RV2TI), and as you see, it has separate audio and mic connectors for your new headset.

If you haven't finished your order to buy that Logitech headset, there is an even better product - [a standalone USB headset like this Logitech one.](http://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/usb-headset-h540)

This one may seem to be expensive, but there are many cheaper alternatives like MS LifeChat LX-3000. This sort of products are also acting as sound cards. Using a Bluetooth headset is another good option as it doesn't take a port at all.

To sum up - if you haven't bought anything yet, buying a standalone USB headset or a Bluetooth one will eliminate all of your headaches. If you've bought a headset already, there's still a chance to buy a USB sound adaptor to avoid pinout investigation.

Comment: That's one option - but that means somewhat more complexity (you have another piece of kit to carry around), and takes up an additional USB port.

Comment: Journeyman// I am suggesting this as cyberweb was already trying to buying an adaptor. If he accepts to use that adaptor, there is no difference to use this adaptor in terms of carriage and complexity at all (headset -> adaptor -> laptop). The USB port is a downside, but the benefit is being able to bypass the pinout issue caused by Apple - Android difference.